# docker image not including all settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Been tugging my declining hairline with this for a few hours now..

Edit: Dockerfile for my image:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache AS webserver
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    && apt-get install -y libzip-dev \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dom enchant exif ffi fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8 odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip
COPY install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions soap openssl gd pdo_mysql bcmath curl exif gettext gmp iconv imap json ldap mbstring mysqli session
COPY conf/custom_php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini

# Copy Data
COPY dump/gnf_noah.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY www/ /var/www/html/

ENV MYSQL_HOST=db
# db As defined in docker-compose.yaml
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password!
ENV MYSQL_USER=gnf_user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password!
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=gnf_noah
```

Having a docker-compose.yaml consisting of this:

```
networks:
  backend: {}
  frontend: {}
services:
  db:
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gnf_noah
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password!
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password!
      MYSQL_USER: gnf_user
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      backend: null
    ports:
    - published: 3306
      target: 3306
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/lakn/noahbuild/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:rw
    - /home/lakn/noahbuild/conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf:rw
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password!
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password!
      MYSQL_USER: gnf_user
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
    - db:db
    networks:
      backend: null
      frontend: null
    ports:
    - published: 30008
      target: 80
    - target: 80
  www:
    build:
      context: /home/lakn/noahbuild
    depends_on:
    - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gnf_noah
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password!
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password!
      MYSQL_USER: gnf_user
    expose:
    - '80'
    - '443'
    links:
    - db
    networks:
      backend: null
      frontend: null
    ports:
    - published: 30001
      target: 80
    - published: 30443
      target: 443
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/lakn/noahbuild/www:/var/www/html:rw
version: '3.2'
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

(apart from the change passwords) it works when doing

```
#docker-compose up --build
```

I get a few images:

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
noahbuild_www           latest              34ef23e328ca        9 minutes ago       510MB
osomanden/debian-noah   latest              a3014cbf2c4b        23 minutes ago      510MB
php                     7.4-apache          1b97367f8c10        6 days ago          414MB
mysql                   latest              0d64f46acfd1        8 days ago          544MB
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   latest              9d4ec4bbd5e5        12 days ago         469MB
```

I tag the image to my repo name.

```
docker tag noahbuild_www osomanden/debian-noah
```

So, I upload osomanden/debian-noah (to my private hub.docker.com repo)

```
docker push osomanden/debian-noah
```

All good. No errors and I am a happy camper.. Image done, works and pushed to repo.

Deletes containers and images to get an empty work environment.

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

and images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Empty environment, I now pull the previously image:

```
docker pull osomanden/debian-noah
```

and run it:

```
# docker run osomanden/debian-noah
```

and gets this result:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Aug 13 09:18:17.375642 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 13 09:18:17.378541 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Where is the database, phpmyadmin and so forth?

Doing an inspect:

```
docker inspect osomanden/debian-noah
```

gives:

```
# docker inspect osomanden/debian-noah
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:a3014cbf2c4bcbbc32c2481cc52c0d0d6394e956fc49ab0f7a2b61533e199f65",
        "RepoTags": [
            "osomanden/debian-noah:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "osomanden/debian-noah@sha256:880a719366df1075cedf88484df98c1e7e5040d2a321f000c831d532156065ac"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2020-08-13T08:48:58.847245858Z",
        "Container": "ebd8c3d7c9f37c7fda19d750060c4d90e434519e83277806b484566a94b2d3e7",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "ebd8c3d7c9f3",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
                "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
                "PHP_VERSION=7.4.9",
                "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.9.tar.xz",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.9.tar.xz.asc",
                "PHP_SHA256=23733f4a608ad1bebdcecf0138ebc5fd57cf20d6e0915f98a9444c3f747dc57b",
                "PHP_MD5=",
                "MYSQL_HOST=db",
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password!",
                "MYSQL_USER=gnf_user",
                "MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password!",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=gnf_noah"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=gnf_noah"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:d8771dd6a3167458e460b9703d15d99719252f9d0682a032205f0fa8a2f222e4",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-php-entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGWINCH"
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
                "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
                "PHP_VERSION=7.4.9",
                "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.9.tar.xz",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.9.tar.xz.asc",
                "PHP_SHA256=23733f4a608ad1bebdcecf0138ebc5fd57cf20d6e0915f98a9444c3f747dc57b",
                "PHP_MD5=",
                "MYSQL_HOST=db",
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password!",
                "MYSQL_USER=gnf_user",
                "MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_password!",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=gnf_noah"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "apache2-foreground"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:d8771dd6a3167458e460b9703d15d99719252f9d0682a032205f0fa8a2f222e4",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-php-entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null,
            "StopSignal": "SIGWINCH"
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 509809162,
        "VirtualSize": 509809162,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e46d389e9ba8ddeb16041400fb510fee9b8d85df1bd630880b6fb5ed8666aed4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eadef676c489b43e437596db05f122b67f359cf4c90c4b0e0ad14442f8c55283/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d1637c8b4d880da8be74b3c8aee2f7335d1893e6a8451be7e1b6a74a5c962c21/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4b115610d8d607cac54862fdc60599d7070a3d33270ccc2ff35f97e966a8fd37/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/46d70ce45a04c8db38320446726b23d3cdf082ced389fa5bf3c6268488e84448/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/72372ffe4c5551a13f585f6c16cd2f72ebd7e17718d26b505153ab31c115eafc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c54a13ee153c3b6498d98ef3c236a64cb549dd1437b65085a216504974daade/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a258066f2bbc54d7a313f6e9f5b7ff3d89bf454ef5563ebff224177f94865090/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/91e110fc4428ba40a51019260b4c909d7bb71d55ff5b27ee304e35b6226feef7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/275c8bfecd876ddd273990e90b3bd4ec79f355236e8c069f6a726902fa7c3439/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/322d31691bdc0d16e7266a7bfaf401128c88124f7539f60dca6c1efb1fa655d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b47f2c38ee1913f8ee70171a664db86d25705478b3b030ed17364dc80dd0cf74/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0ae651690c8519329381cee847bc0860fa4a77df961aa5f04fbccab99b440062/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/75ac057961490fbcb3c765c6cc1572e144620e03e017c81c6b1d548414a57e3a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a65fe1b906f422ae16511fff9c54298fc7cb1a49b85546548a990f79fc95044c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f22f0aff914419a3d28e99519aa26ccc586d042d945e637e954a0cc8c4444521/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e163c66142d1f0cf30b85d6a31f07abfc2cd419bf4e60fe8165b437481f00039/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4dcaa9ee8cc47c337fa0bcca662f7acbb884b22e12b4909eb0213a263613c9ed/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/42f002b441a73ceb68e2615de318985b36afdd21c6b3ea75f33a9c84fd3e46d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6453968ccee37015c40301110c537d62327198141b18ddf62201f78610985175/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2554d9a6fd332d5dfc3d3c20ee06a4c4f3713a31a0be61fc05e7db44a7b32657/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2554d9a6fd332d5dfc3d3c20ee06a4c4f3713a31a0be61fc05e7db44a7b32657/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2554d9a6fd332d5dfc3d3c20ee06a4c4f3713a31a0be61fc05e7db44a7b32657/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:d0f104dc0a1f9c744b65b23b3fd4d4d3236b4656e67f776fe13f8ad8423b955c",
                "sha256:8bf7a47284aac0c2761a2a777da54bb40593f6dd53dd9625b79132630967e007",
                "sha256:de5ed450c2e9c7f71f7b7984c941f323f6484f6ebb9dc200bced161feafe0377",
                "sha256:65bff11b305bf56c86c73d895a6079158677f35c3dc5a6feec1f97d1f8230a97",
                "sha256:7edde2b8acef9f72eb9a6c7a8946b843420bd51f5097b64d10ac30fa396bb123",
                "sha256:b325a1cca10d4162df013dd6dc94d50d7fd196537f28df4248ead0951940bb8e",
                "sha256:c7ba9188a7f66fce22fbb8aeb5a029d1103b81a1fd38e7cd091839e0dd2c7e29",
                "sha256:c890d6fb7f00943fe075662ca0b142c46c2654057ed12baa39d391752f2dc429",
                "sha256:df61ee63abe40d703c763e0c64e0d3b00e3c79b57356880901577ee288d30dc1",
                "sha256:2facc097999b883eb29632f1c999ffdea6b5878ef227b532681c5af57e2bb3fe",
                "sha256:edc5481917da0bfc0ac40ac83c145beeb765a1bbf8d9da0a956d8b8329f380ff",
                "sha256:6fa199c4fdeb77bc1e2a89bf6d8c3d54a569119f9144389cce8f990c1b573098",
                "sha256:09b9e3584f90fa9fa1c246e06260b4ea27258236a40d74ebf96f40313e77fc55",
                "sha256:d7dd3a080c9ab2ffde19d7cfb85faf020e132a9ba7a616b2874fac09812260aa",
                "sha256:7e9b0f30ff95f95ef79d1f12edf4d57823c56d01faedda89c8c20601f9228635",
                "sha256:1bee028f5b3e5d1495ddc75ffe5d79529d0634917ae5a5e8e166d416bf41a1e3",
                "sha256:ded2df4620b28d8b88821c9d363f963ebcb5cdc6399cc1bbc01c52bfd47c79f8",
                "sha256:c603099ece17d8187c5bccefaa8964c77f96bc3d55a9f84e469d445f6d547985",
                "sha256:881bf6dc67e8fb52dbf396951a94a00b04629fc8fc4420fcfe0d6fed80c07fa0",
                "sha256:0ad79670460ea103f6f8f292af6cafadd0c52a4ef86c592b992c18359f57180e",
                "sha256:ff00ffefb91d54d78527b30a9826b698b2c910a33a6dd0038f6a5e9b784b30f1"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Even my expose to port 443 is gone.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Oh, btw:

```
#docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:45:50 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:44:21 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know if I get this right, but to the `Where is the database, phpmyadmin and so forth?`point - These are different, standalone docker images that have nothing to do with the `noahbuild_www` image. docker-compose is just the kind of "glue" to let these more or less isolated services talk to each other. `context: /home/lakn/noahbuild` means, in this directory should be a Dockerfile. This file, not docker-compose, is responsible for building your www image. maybe post the contents of the file here as well

Comment: Forgot to show the Dockerfile. Editing question now.

Comment: alright, but my point stands. for example port 443 is not exposed because it is not exposed in the Dockerfile but only in the compose file. Also like I said, every docker image that is created by `docker-compose up` stands for itself. So your `noahbuild_www`  image has no knowledge at all of the database or phpmyadmin image. They are designed to communicate over network, in docker-compose context this is handled "automatically"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're confusing 3 different things.

Images: definition used to create containers. Consist of filesystem layers and a default configuration. This is defined by a Dockerfile.

Containers: instance created from an image, programmers tend to think of this as an object vs a class. This instance may have many configuration options overridden.

Docker Compose: used to parse a yml file with all the configuration options to run a collection of containers. It also has the ability to kick off an image build using a passed Dockerfile.

When you use `docker run` you are creating a container that uses none of the compose file settings. And if you inspect the image, you will only see the result of the Dockerfile's build. If you want the collection of containers with networking and volumes configured according to the yml file, you need to run `docker-compose` commands like:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Note, I'd also recommend including an image name for your private registry in the compose file. Then you can run `docker-compose push` and other nodes so not need to run a build again.

Comment: Seems I have to agree ;-) But how do I get the image to initiate opening additional mysql and phpmyadmin images.

I have to have an instruction (docker-compose.yml) for users to run with the image.. 
Something like, run this yml file - it will download and run these images into one usable container - have I understood the workings of it ?

Comment: @osomanden Yes, pull this yml and run "docker-compose up -d" should be the instructions. There's also "docker app" that is merging the two steps, but it hasn't gained traction yet.